# NSTextView does not display data until mouse passes over

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion

I'm experiencing a strange behavior in Lion with NSTextView instances. I set attributed strings to them through its text storage interface but the data does not display until I pass the mouse cursor over each NSTextView instance. In Snow Leopard I have no problems
Does anyone have any idea what could be happening?

Comment: Are you doing everything on the main thread?

Comment: I have a secondary thread checking the weather... curious thing is that I have other NSTextView instances not affected, and I cannot detect the difference...

Comment: Try doing the actual updates on the main thread (you can/should still do the weather checks on the background thread)...

Comment: I think I'm doing that already, once I finish reading the weather info I call "[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateInternalInfo:) withObject:xmlWrapper waitUntilDone:NO];" then on UpdateInternalInfo I just inform the delegate that the info is ready.

Comment: jtbandes are you using Lion? Can I send you a promo code of my app? Maybe if you can see it you can see through it? ... let me know.

Comment: I am, but I don't think that will help. I believe you that it doesn't show up until mouseover, but I don't have any idea what to do about it.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this issue? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: No, what's your view hierarchy setup ?

Comment: View hierarchy is fairly deep.

Window -> SplitView -> View -> SplitView -> TabView -> TabItem -> TextView. I've tried manually updating the object as well using [textView setNeedsDisplay: YES], but that did not help either.

Comment: I opened a technical support with Apple several months ago. They asked me for a sample project with the bug, but had no time to do this. If you have one, I can re-open the support.

Comment: You should probably post the code you’re using.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're changing the model behind the view's back. Are you calling -beginEditing before your changes and -endEditing after?